# PrimeNG table row width change on rowExpand

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I'm using PrimeNG table with expandable rows. However when I trigger the expand event all of the parent rows decrease in width, as seen in the images below:

[Table before expansion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llISf.png)

[Table after expansion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGaWd.png)

How can I implement the row expansion feature without changing the width of the parent row?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The colspan attribute for the expanded row was set to 12, although there were only 10 columns for the original table (I thought colspan was related to the html grid view hence I set it to 12. Rookie error I know...)

Setting the colspan attribute to the number of rows as seen below solved this issue.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion" let-filteredGallery>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind to an attribute use  `[attr.colspan]="10"`

```
  <ng-template pTemplate="rowexpanssion" let-columns> 
    <tr>
       <td [attr.colspan]="10">
           //code
       </td>
    </tr>
 </ng-template>
```

Here, colspan is not a property of td element. colspan is an attribute. so we have to add prefix attr to colspan to tell angular that it is an attribute.